# how can a loader be part of compilation in c program?

Tags: compilation, loader

loader is considered as part of compilation process ,but actually loader's job is to load the code into main memory,but compiler keeps the .out file in hard disk only .
then why is loader considered as part of compilation ,please respond in view of c programming language

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,got the answer,
sometimes we compile and execute the program ,e.g
when we interpret the program instead of compiling ,then compiler and loader
will work together,otherwise,after compilation process is finished then only we can run the program (to run ,loader should load the executable program into memory).